# Date function changing DD-MM-YYYY to MM-DD-YYYY output

Tags: excel, vba, validation, date

I'm setting up a userform for employees to fill in data. They need to fill in the date like DD-MM-YYYY the output must also be DD-MM-YYYY. However the code I use changes input 5-12-2019 (DD-MM-YYYY), to output 12-5-2019 (MM-DD-YYYY). In the userform it stays like (DD-MM-YYYY) expect for when you tranfer it to your excel sheet. If the month is above 13 it doesn't change, so input 13-12-2019 (DD-MM-YYYY) stays output 13-12-2019 (DD-MM-YYYY). How is it possible that the code changes the output but not everytime the same way, did I do something wrong in the code?

```
Private Sub TextBox1_BeforeUpdate(ByVal cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
    If IsDate(Me.TextBox1.Text) Then
        Me.TextBox1.Text = Format(Me.TextBox1.Text, "DD-MM-YYYY")
    Else
        MsgBox "Vul een geldige datum in", vbRetryCancel + vbCritical
    End If

End Sub

Public Function IsTime(Expression As Variant) As Boolean
    If IsDate(Expression) Then
        IsTime = (Int(CSng(CDate(Expression))) = 0)
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: Instead of asking them for a date in string format, you could ask them for year, month and day separately and then construct a date from those values.

Comment: @jsheeran - 3 different fields in a data entry form? Just to enter a date?

Comment: When transferring it to the sheet, use `CDate`

Comment: @Vityata Think of the web forms you may have encountered in the days when they were written in bare HTML rather than with a JavaScript date picker. Those generally had 3 separate fields, and weren't too strenuous to fill out.

Comment: @jsheeran - I do not say it is impossible or not done, but having work as something close to date-entry-operator, I pity the people who would use it.

Comment: @Vityata The people using it might be puzzled by your pity; pressing tab between month, day, and year is no more strenuous than pressing dash.

Comment: @L.ScottJohnson - well, it depends. What if you are coping the date from somewhere? This is a quite viable scenario. Or if you need to copy back the date you have entered as a backup? Anyway, three textboxes for a date does not seem good UI to me.

Comment: I believe the reason for the difference is because some background date conversions logic.. guessing it is based off Regional Settings.  Assuming your regional settings are (MM-DD-YYYY).  5-12-2019, 5 and 12 could both be days or months so it would assume the date is in your regional settings, and convert it.  13-12-2019, 13 has to be a day and therefore 12 is the month.  It's already in the desired format so no change is made.... incoming rant about dates.  :p

Comment: <Rant> That being said you shouldn't use either of these formats, the only date format that should be used is YYYY-MM-DD (ISO 8601).  This date format is sortable as text. It starts from largest unit to smallest unit, and continues the trend when accompanied by time hh:mm:ss. </Rant>

Comment: @JosephC My regional settings are Nederlands (Dutch) and we use DD-MM-YYYY as our main date format. Maybe it's indeed better to use the ISO 8601 format

Answer (score 1):

1. Read the date as a string. E.g. `5-12-2009`.
2. Split the string by `-`.
3. The 0th value is the day, the 1st is the month, the 2nd is the year.
4. From there, you have a fully functioning date, using `DateSerial()`.

---

```
Public Function StringToDate(myInput As String) As Date

    Dim day As Long
    Dim month As Long
    Dim year As Long
    Dim dateArray As Variant

    dateArray = Split(myInput, "-")
    day = dateArray(0)
    month = dateArray(1)
    year = dateArray(2)

    StringToDate = DateSerial(year, month, day)

End Function

Public Sub Main()

    Debug.Print month(StringToDate("05-10-2001"))
    Debug.Print StringToDate("05-10-2001")

End Sub
```